# Form submit when button with font awesome icon is clicked

Tags: javascript, html

Form properly gets submitted with proper functionalities, but when clicked on font icon then it is not able to get the value and name from button...

```
<form onsubmit="handleSubmit(event)">
  <div class="buttons"> 
    <button name="super" value="12344321" type="submit"  class="btn btn info"> Submit 
      <i class="fas fa-arrow-right"></i> 
    </button>
  </div>
</form>
```

Here is my js code:

```
event.submitter.setAttribute('disabled', 'disabled');
let name= event.submitter.name;
console.log("name" +name);
let id = event.submitter.value;
console.log("id " +id);
```

Comment: seems to work for me - what happens at your end?

Comment: name and value get null value

Comment: It works on my end: https://jsfiddle.net/hdtjrq6o/  But If it still doesn't work for you, try adding `.btn svg {pointer-events: none;}` to your css.

Comment: @ProgRank - which browser and version?